# How to get the name of the relationship for inner queries in SOQL?

Tags: soql, relationships, trailhead, inner

In Trailhead we have the query to get the Contacts for the Account named "SFDC Computing", with an inner query.

```
 SELECT Name, (SELECT LastName FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Name = 'SFDC Computing'
```

It works fine for my purposes. 
"Contacts" is the name of the relationship, per Trailhead.
So, I went to Object Manager and examined the Account object's "Fields and Relationships". There is nothing named "Contacts"!

In general, how do I get the name of the relationship, for use in similar SOQL queries?

Comment: I've linked four other questions that demonstrate a number of ways to find the relationship, including Apex Code, workbench, etc, as well.

Answer (score 2):

You look at the relationship lookup field on the child object. Here's an example from `Contact`, whose lookup field to `Account` is `AccountId`:

[image]

For custom relationship fields, the relationship name must be postfixed with `__r` in SOQL, and queries against objects in a different namespace must be prefixed with the relevant namespace, i.e., `MyNs__My_Relationship__r`.