# Data binding between 2 custom objects

Tags: visualforce, cpq, databinding

According to the below article, easy way to bind all child records when we use a standard controller is {!Account.Contacts} - {!Parent.RelationshipName of Child}

```
 <apex:repeat value="**{!Account.Contacts}**" var="line">
      <tr>
         <td>{!line.Name}</td>
         <td>{!line.Phone}</td>
      </tr>
   </apex:repeat>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_access_data.htm

Now instead of Account, I have a custom parent object from CPQ package - SBQQ__Quote__c 
Instead of contact, I have a custom child object from CPQ package -  SBQQ__QuoteLine__c
How to bind these to objects together to get a list of all quote lines when using a Quote standard controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to the below article, easy way to bind all child records when we use a standard controller is {!Account.Contacts} - {!Parent.PluralAPIName of Child}

This is an incorrect reading of the document. The child relationship name is the relationship name, which with standard objects is *typically* the plural of the API name of the child.

To find the relationship name, [look at the relationship field on the child object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235498/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-relationship-for-inner-queries-in-soql/235499#235499). Note that with custom objects it will end in `__r`.

Comment: +1 Took the text right outta my text field .

Comment: Thanks so much for the guidance. I was also looking at the wrong child object! That's why I was getting the error :D 

Finally I narrowed the child object to SBQQ__LineItems__c. 
Steps followed : 
1. Exported the Enterprise WSDL
2. Look for type="tns:QueryResult" under the SBQQ__Quote__c Object and pinned down the relationship name!